# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) - Como resolvo?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**O site só dá erro no servidor, localmente ta tudo bem!
Olha:**

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)) Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web            request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is
>   denied. (Exception   from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access   rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity    (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the   configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> - Line 1:  @{
> - Line 2:  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("BancoDeDados",    "Tabela", "Coluna1", "Coluna2", true);

Comment: Qual versão do MS SQL? 2005 ?
Qual versão do IIS no SErver?

Comment: SQL SERVER CE, e o IIS no Server não sei dizer a versão más acho que é a mais recente!

Answer (score 1):

o seu ASP.NET no servidor não tem autorização para rodar.
no IIS você deverá dar permissão.
Coloco primeiro a permissão na pasta no servidor (Apenas para teste coloque o usuário Everyone com permissão full) o correto é o {nome_da_maquina}\ASSPNET ou IUSR_Nome_Maquina.

Deve funcioná.

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: onde esta rodando essa aplicação? Servidor? tablet? onde esta esse servidor?(é uma hospedagem ou ele é seu?) se for hospedagem no painel da hospedagem tem sempre um local para permissões.

Comment: Servidor de Hospedagem!

Comment: Eu encontrei como alterar algumas configurações no arquivo ou na pasta. Tem lá tipo - > IIS Account (-), eu já dei permissão onde podia no arquivo.sdf (banco de dados) e o erro continua. Você sabe o que fazer?

Comment: da permissão na pasta onde esta o ASP.NET

Comment: Como assim o ASP.NET?

Comment: isso que dá não explicar direito...sua pergunta esta muito 'jogada' assim vamos chutando o que pode lhe ajudar.
Vc não desenvolveu uma aplicação em C# em asp.net? pelo menos as tags que vc colocou foram disso. imaginando que na hospedagem tenha lá permissões de pasta, eu colocaria permissão de execução onde se encontra seus arquivos asp.net qualquer caso entre em contato com a hospedagem, eles saberão o problema.

Comment: Valeu cara! sim eu fiz em asp.net, c#. faz o seguinte responde mais não tá. E vota lá contra (se não já votou), denuncia, tenta excluir, sei lá. blz?!

Comment: @Glorious, não precisa esquentar, foi apenas uma critica construtiva.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o problema é o seguinte:

O Sql Ce precisa de permissão de leitura e escrita na pasta App_Data.

E além disso precisa de permissão de leitura e execução nos arquivos binários que estão na pasta bin\amd64 e bin\x86, que é a pasta onde estão as DLL's do SQL CE.